# Ubuntu Mysql Server not allowing remote connections

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I've looked in so many areas to try to fix this problem and I can't seem to find a solution. Im running ubuntu linux with the latest mysql and phpmyadmin installation. I found that connecting to the database locally works but if I try to connect remotely it keeps denying the connections. The only way I can login to phpmyadmin is if I put the ip address in the bar, connecting via the web address will not work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to MySQL remotely or PHPMyAdmin remotely?

If you are trying to access MySQL remotely, you need to do the following:

- Edit the *bind-address* variable in */etc/my.cnf*, to 0.0.0.0 or the IP address of your server
- Make sure your MySQL user has permissions from remote hosts, do this using:

  **CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';**

  **CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';**
- Then:

  **GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';**

  **GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';**

Then go ahead and restart the mysql instance on your server. This also assumes you have set IP tables up to allow port 3306 TCP incoming to your server.